# Network Information System (NIS) with Openstack Keystone

Tags: keystone, nis

Is there any way through which Network Information System (NIS) could be integrated with Openstack Keystone?
Please let me know if you know any online resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on Openstack Keystone v3 documentation.
We can extent authentication support in keystone in following three ways:

1. Configure Openstack keystone with Apache server and handover authentication part to Apache
2. Write middileware in Openstack keystone
3. Extend Openstack keystone functionality by writing authentication plugin

> http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-keystoneclient/authentication-plugins.html#authentication-plugins

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of box support for NIS in keystone. but you can always write your own custom backend for keystone. Check --> [Custom Backend](https://thestaticvoid.com/post/2013/06/04/customizing-the-openstack-keystone-authentication-backend/)